how to make a mask that disables cloth physics on a defined area
It's as the title says, I want to make a mask that makes the cloth physics on a specified area. I know that is related to Geometry Nodes but I can't find any tutorial that explains that.
To make an example I have a sphere that is inflating by tweaking the pressure settings on the cloth tab and I want a mask with a shape of a plane mesh that allows me to turn the object back to normal on the area of effect of the mask.
I specifically want to obtain this effect but in this case, it was made with shape keys:
https://x.com/HeavyWomanGuy/status/1775752125131141218

The mask what you are looking for is the Shape > Pin Group of the cloth simulation settings. Here you can define a vertex group. Vertices with a weight of 1.0 are pinned and not affected by the simulation. They can be animated by key frames, armature or hooks. All other vertices are deformed by the cloth simulation. The influence depends on the vertex weight.
Here is an example animation of an expanding ball that bursts a rope wrapped around it:

The center edge loop of the ball and all vertices of the rope object are in a pin group. Both objects have a cloth simulation. To release the pin set the Pin weight to 0.0.
This can be done with a Vertex Weight Edit modifier or a Geometry Nodes modifier.
The Vertex Weight Edit modifier clears the Pin group by setting the Group Remove Threshold to 1.0 at frame 51. For frames 1 and 50 the value of the Group Remove Threshold is 0.0, so nothing changes.

Alternatively, you can use a little Geometry Nodes modifier. It sets the weight of the vertices in the group Selection to Value setting.
In this case you need 2 vertex groups. One for the selection (=center edge loop, weight 1.0) and the Pin group for the cloth settings. The weight will be set by the Geometry Nodes modifier (=Value setting).

There are key frames for the Value setting. For frames 1 to 50 it's 1.0 to pin the cloth at the center. And at frame 51 the Value is set to 0.0 to release the pin.
Additionally, the Pressure is increased (from   0 to 270 for 50 frames, then set to 50 at frame 52) and the Shrinking Factor is decreased slightly (frame 1: 0, frame 21: -0.25). The ball is 1.69m at the beginning, 2.21m at the end.
The ball and the floor have Collision physics enabled. Note that the order of the ball's modifier is important.
If you want to make the ball less wobbly try to lower the Cloth > Physical Properties > Vertex Mass setting of the Cloth physics.
Happy bursting!
